# Why can't I pass an object to `navigation.navigate()`?

Tags: react-native-navigation, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm using the UI Kitten library. I can store routes in an array and pass an array index to `navigate()`

Here's what I'm doing. I store my routes in an array like this:

```
const routeNames = [
  'Customers',
  'Employees',
]
```

And then I reference them on a navigation tab:

```
<BottomNavigation
    selectedIndex={state.index}
    onSelect={onSelect}
>
  <BottomNavigationTabItem
      title={routeNames[0]}
  />
...
```

And handle on select:

```
const onSelect = index => {
    navigation.navigate(routeNames[index]);
  };
```

But I would rather reference their name for better readability like this:

```
<BottomNavigationTabItem
          title={routeNames.Customer}
      />
```

And therefore store the route names in an object:

```
const routeNames = {
      CustomerList: 'Customers',
      EmployeeList: 'Employees',
    }
```

But doing it this way with the object gives me an error:

> You need to specify name or key when calling navigate with an object
> as the argument

I feel like it shouldn't matter as long as I pass a string for the route name.

UPDATE: It looks like [the docs say a number type is required for `onSelect`](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/bottom-tabs/api#:%7E:text=currently%20selected%20tab.-,onSelect,-(number)%20%3D%3E%20void) ... but is the array index not referencing a string?
What do I not understand about how array references work?

Comment: probably in `onSelect` you can't access an item from `routeNames` by `index` because it is an object and `routesNames[index]` is undefined.

Comment: Oops should be `routeNames.index`. Edited to fix